# Mongodb replicaset indexes removing

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a mongo replicaset that uses N indexes. Now i want to remove some of them (indexes). How can i do this? When i am trying to drop index on master it works, but after indexes appear again, from slave (apparently).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: They shouldn't reappear. Can you give an example.

Comment: It could be a bug of rockmongo that I use. I understand, they must not reappear.

Comment: we could probably discuss this more easily on mongodb-user